# How to get the Variable name dynamically in below example

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to the python. Please excuse me if explanation is not upto the mark.Below piece of code will return n.left =0 , n.right =1  and n.centre =1

```
from argparse import Namespace
n = Namespace(**cust_dic)
n
Namespace(left='0', right='1', centre='1')
```

I am trying to create the variable's name as below :

```
 eg : left = n.left
      right = n.right
      centre = n.centre
```

How we can create variable name as key name of the dictionary dynamically ?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have there?

Comment: How we can create variable name as key name of the dictionary?

Comment: Why do you want that? Why not just use `n.left` etc. as you have them now? (It's possible to do what you're asking, but generally discouraged. Dicts were designed for this sort of thing.)

Comment: d = { 'A' : '0', 'B' :'t', 'C' : '7'}
for key in d:
   exec("{0} = {1}".format(key, d[key]))    .  this code is giving error while creating the name as Key and assigning key value.   When Values of the keys is integer, its working fine.

Comment: So you want to be able to access the attributes using a string? Use [`getattr(n, 'left')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).